# is the print shipping label option by default in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to print shipping label of an order. Print Shipping Label option is available in the Actions on the admin order grid. But when I print the label it displays an error.

> "There are no shipping labels related to selected orders."

I have followed the tutorial:

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-labels-create.html

according to this:

> "In the lower-right corner, select the Create Shipping Label
>   checkbox."

but I didn't find this option. Can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: Which shipping method you are using. The shipping label is provided by the shipping agency.

Comment: Now, flat rate is using. is it the dependency of shipping method?

Comment: You can found code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370384/magento-how-to-create-shipping-label-dynamically/54938158#54938158 Good luck